# How to pin multiple elements (inside each other) with not 100vh?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollmagic

I'm trying to achieve a Site with ScrollMagic.
[Example Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqNVvb)

```
.section {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  max-height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.section:last-child {
  background: green;
}

.section > div {
  height: 100%;
}

.sub-1-1 { background: #1abc9c; }
.sub-1-2 { background: #f1c40f; }
.sub-1-3 { background: #e74c3c; }
.sub-2-1 { background: #9b59b6; }
.sub-2-2 { background: #34495e; }
.sub-2-3 { background: #95a5a6; }

.foo,
.bar {
  height: 1200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```
var smc = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var container = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '.container',
  triggerHook: 'onLeave',
  duration: '250%',
  pushFollower: false,
  offset: -60
}).setPin('.container').addTo(smc);

var section2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '.section-2',
  triggerHook: 'onLeave',
  duration: '250%',
  pushFollower: false,
}).setPin('.section-2').addTo(smc);
```

Explaination:

- Red content (top + bottom) has variable height. Should always stick to their next/previous elements (no space between).
- Yellow and Green content should stick at top + 60px if they reach this position and scroll "inside" (html structure has 3x section for each)

My problem:

- Can't reduce the space between red and yellow / green and red.
- Can't set an top 60 offset of green with sticking yellow on it.

Instead of hoping for a fully working prototype I appreciate someone to show me the way. Thanks!